# How can extract framework from Cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm working with the objective-c library [OCR Mobile Vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/ios/text-overview), but i need Cocoapods with this implementation.

I have to extract the framework and add to Xcode Swift Project.

This is the Cocoapods site:
https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleMobileVision

I didn't find the instructions for separate the framework on the site.

Comment: actually u just open the website of cocoapods, search for the pod, open details and go to the linked source website.

Comment: @BjörnRo on the site https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleMobileVision i didn't find the instructions for that

Comment: @maxwellnewage this is the podspec https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/4/2/GoogleMobileVision/1.2.0/GoogleMobileVision.podspec.json here u can finde everything u need. in source link you can download the cod ei think, but u have to load the dependencies as well. Or just put them in you podfile. to be honest, dont load the plugin in your app  Maybe the pod is just not what u need. You try to read text from a picture? Than you should use teserract 

Comment: So do you mean that you can't use cocoapods? You want to use the framework but without using cocoapods? in that case I think you'd need the source code from Github or something, but I can't seem to find much.. this is their documentation: https://developers.google.com/vision/ios/getting-started but that's all I could find

Comment: @JoniVR i think he wants to modify the code of the pod

Comment: @BjörnRo In that case he should be able to go into the "Pods" project once installed and then look for it in there, although idk if cocoapods supports any kind of closed source where you can't view the source code. Never seen it before though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of working with a CocoaPod is following the instructions from your [first link](https://developers.google.com/vision/ios/text-overview). See the *Creating the text detector* section.

If you really want to pull the framework out of the CocoaPod. Load the [link](https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/9cd291875037094d/GoogleMobileVision-1.2.0.tar.gz) from the source attribute in the [podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/4/2/GoogleMobileVision/1.2.0/GoogleMobileVision.podspec.json) to get a tar.gz file with the pod contents.